# UDP Multicast recvfrom reading same datagram multiple times

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, udp, multicast

I have a simple UDP multicast program in which the main thread spawns two worker threads. All three share one UDP multicast socket. Right now this program works, though the recvfrom call is happening twice per packet. Perhaps the first time it is called, it's not properly clearing the receive buffer? If so, how would I go about fixing this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MULTICAST_PORT 23456
#define MULTICAST_ADDRESS "239.255.24.25"
#define MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE 256

using namespace std;

struct sockaddr_in sendaddr;
socklen_t sendaddrlen;
int sock;
string username;
pthread_mutex_t mut;

void print(string message) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    printf("%s\n", message.c_str());
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
}

void *sender_actor(void *arg) {

    // Prepare Message
    string message = "ANNOUNCE " + username;
    long bytes_sent;

    while (true) {
        print("sender thread: preparing to send message");
        bytes_sent = sendto(sock, message.c_str(), message.length() + 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sendaddr, sendaddrlen);
        print("sender thread: sent message");
        if (bytes_sent < 0) {
            cerr << "sendto failed" << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        sleep(60);
    }

    return 0;
}

void *recipient_actor(void *arg) {

    // Declare Address
    struct sockaddr_in other;
    socklen_t otherlen;

    // Prepare Buffer
    long bytes_received;
    char message_buffer[MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE];

    while (true) {
        print("receiver thread: preparing to receive message");
        bytes_received = recvfrom(sock, message_buffer, MESSAGE_BUFFER_SIZE, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&other, &otherlen);
        if (bytes_received < 0) {
            cerr << "recvfrom failed" << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        print("receiver thread: received message:");
        print(message_buffer);
    }

    return 0;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    // Check arguments:
    if (argc != 2) {
        cerr << "invalid number of arguments" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Extract username:
    username = argv[1];

    // Create a UDP socket:
    sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP);
    if (sock < 0) {
        cerr << "failed to create socket" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Allow multiple sockets for the port:
    u_int yes = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes)) < 0) {
        perror("Reusing ADDR failed");
        exit(1);
    }

    // Setup destination address:
    struct sockaddr_in recvaddr;
    memset(&recvaddr,0,sizeof(recvaddr));
    recvaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    recvaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    recvaddr.sin_port = htons(MULTICAST_PORT);
    socklen_t recvaddrlen = sizeof(recvaddr);

    // Bind the socket to the address:
    if (bind(sock,(struct sockaddr *) &recvaddr, sizeof(recvaddr)) < 0) {
        cerr << "bind failed" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Join multicast group:
    struct ip_mreq mreq;
    mreq.imr_multiaddr.s_addr = inet_addr(MULTICAST_ADDRESS);
    mreq.imr_interface.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_MEMBERSHIP, &mreq, sizeof(mreq)) < 0) {
        cerr << "setsockop failed" << endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Create sender thread:
    pthread_t sender_thread;
    pthread_create(&sender_thread, NULL, sender_actor, NULL);

    // Create recipient thread:
    pthread_t recipient_thread;
    pthread_create(&recipient_thread, NULL, recipient_actor, NULL);

    // Initialize Send Address
    memset(&sendaddr,0,sizeof(sendaddr));
    sendaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    sendaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(MULTICAST_ADDRESS);
    sendaddr.sin_port = htons(MULTICAST_PORT);
    sendaddrlen = sizeof(sendaddr);

    // Read input and send messages:
    long bytes_sent;
    string message;
    while (true) {
        getline(cin, message);
        message = "FROM:" + username + " " + message;
        print("main thread: preparing to send message");
        bytes_sent = sendto(sock,message.c_str(), message.length() + 1, 0, (struct sockaddr *)&sendaddr, sendaddrlen);
        print("main thread: sent message");
        if (bytes_sent < 0) {
            cerr << "sendto failed" << endl;
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `recvfrom` *probably* returns the message length both times, but did youcheck?

Comment: You need to NUL-terminate the string before you print it (e.g. message_buffer[bytes_received]='\0'; ) otherwise you are likely to re-print old data from a previous iteration of your loop.

Comment: @Logan Shire this should have a `c++` tag instead of `c`, but interesting problem ....

Comment: @JeremyFriesner in both the `main` and `send_actor` threads he's sending a `.c_str()` (which guarantees the resulting `char` array is null terminated) and sending `message.length()+1` bytes to include the message and the null byte. Unless `\0` is not getting sent due to some I/O error (worth a check), he should be good on that front. @LoganShire I am unable to duplicate this problem, so either I don't understand it or my machine is luckily cooperating with some undefined behavior. Could you post actual output vs. your expected output?

Comment: @yano relying on the sender to send correct data is insecure.  Even if his sending program always NUL-terminates, nothing stops another program from sending non-NUL-terminated packets.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner excellent point

Comment: There are two `sendto()` calls - one in main thread, one in sender. Why do you think your `recvfrom()` is called twice for the **same** packet?

Comment: @JeremyFriesner, this is just for an assignment to learn about multicast discovery, and it is only being run locally - security isn't really a concern.

Comment: @yano, I put c because most of this project revolves around standard c networking library - the <string> package is really the only c++ construct here. But if you want to make it c++ that's fine.

Comment: @SergeyA, this prints:
sender thread: preparing to send message
sender thread: sent message
once. 
It then prints:
receiver thread: preparing to receive message
receiver thread: received message:
ANNOUNCE logan
twice.

Comment: @LoganShire and namespaces. `c` has no concept of namespaces. I'm not bent out of shape,, just saying... `c` != `c++`. I try to compile this with `gcc` and get 40 errors .. it's not `c` code. But none of my complaining helps solve your problem. I compiled and ran your code. I didn't see anything unexpected. You're getting ANNOUNCE twice? Very strange. I get the prints in different order but we are dealing with multiple threads so that's expected. Don't think I saw ANNOUNCE twice though... hmmm

Comment: @yano yeah, it's strange. are you using osx, linux or windows? i'm on el captain fwiw

Comment: @LoganShire I was using osx snow leopard.  .. 10.6.8 I believe. I really need a new box, heh.